# Java Portlet API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, portlet

I am looking at the Java Portlet API for the first time and trying to decide on whether or not to consider using it.

From the look of things, it looks like a technology that might be considered old school because i seem not to see very current references of its usages.

My question is, would you consider using the Java Portlet API, more so when you are planning to develop an integrated web application consisting of modules that may themselves be separate applications of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

Normally we go for a Portal application (using Portal API) in scenarios like this:

1. Multiple application(Portlets) in same page.
2. Multiple applications in separate pages but uses same Login(or User credentials).
3. Multiple applications which communicate to each other in same page or in different page.

These are just highlevel thoughts. Based on the application and available server stack, the Portal server can be chosen IBM Websphere Portal / Liferay / Weblogic Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Portals are good at providing a common set of services, such as security and UI, to wrap around several applications that have a need to either pass information between them, or a need to be utilized as part of a similar process.

It's worth noting that there is also the [JBoss Portal Platform](https://www.jboss.org/products/jpp.html), in addition to those above.

Also, there is a new version of the Portlet specification currently in development: http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=362